# Is there a way to submit innerHTML of a span within a form?

Tags: html, forms

I have a span element which opens a date picker and then displays the date once it's been picked.

Is there a way to send its content with all the other values?

I am using a hidden input which takes the value of the span when it changes, so I am not stuck, but I was wondering if there is a more straight forward solution.

Thanks, Dan

Comment: using ajax, but I don't think it's more straightforward than using an hidden. Matter of tastes I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for displaying the date in a span element instead of an input box was because I didn't want the users to be able to input a date manually.

I have just found out that there is a readonly attribute for text inputs. Using that instead of that workaround solves my problem.

Thanks for the answers I received while looking for a solution myself anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the W3C HTML 4.01 spec [here(1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name) and [here(2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format), only successful controls will be sent upon form submission.

Successful controls are defined in the second link, while what elements are considered controls are in the first link.

As we expect, only form-related tags are considered valid controls, so the answer is **no**, we cannot submit a span element along with the form.

Comment: Thank you, that was useful to know. I will bookmark those pages!

Answer (score 1):

This seems extremely vague. The most 'straight forward' solution to access element content would be to use javascript, but where do you want to send your value to? A js file? A PHP file?

Anywhere javascript is used, you can access the value of the span directly, but what exactly is going on? When you say it 'opens' a date picker, does this mean it contains a widget, another HTML element, or is is the date picker also an input? Please be more specific about describing the problem.

Comment: Apologies your question made me realise the description wasn't clear! A span displays the current date ( "DD - MM - YYYY" ). The date picker is a div with the current and next 11 months, its display : none. Clicking on the span sets the div as display : inLine. Now that the date picker is visible, the user can click on a day on it. This sets the date picker display : none. It also sets the content of the span to the chosen DD - MM - YYYY, and sets the same value for a hidden input. The span is only used to display the date, the value is submitted from the hidden input.